# Django refuses to accept my one-off default value for FloatField

Tags: python, django

I have a class and I'm trying to add a new `FloatField` to it. Django wants a default value to populate existing rows (reasonable). However, it refuses to accept any value I give it.

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'FIELDNAME' to CLASS without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: -1
Please select a valid option: -1
Please select a valid option: -1
Please select a valid option: float(-1)
Please select a valid option: -1.0
Please select a valid option: float(-1.0)
Please select a valid option:
```

How do I get it to accept my value?

Comment: It's presenting you a menu with two choices, `1` and `2`.  You're typing `-1` which is not a valid choice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should select option 1 and then input your value

```
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
 1
```

After selecting 1. It would ask to provide your default value.

```
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> -1.0
```

Comment: Try 'timezone.now()' instead of '-1.0'. You may get “Expected string or bytes-like object” error if trying with -1.0